# How to deploy sagemaker.workflow.pipeline.Pipeline?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have a `sagemaker.workflow.pipeline.Pipeline` which contains multiple `sagemaker.workflow.steps.ProcessingStep` and each `ProcessingStep` contains `sagemaker.processing.ScriptProcessor`.

The current pipeline graph look like the below shown image. It will take data from multiple sources from S3, process it and create a final dataset using the data from previous steps.

[image]

As the `Pipeline` object doesn't support `.deploy` method, how to deploy this pipeline?

While inference/scoring, When we receive a raw data(single row for each source), how to trigger the pipeline?

or Sagemaker Pipeline is designed for only data processing and model training on huge/batch data? Not for the inference with the single data point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As the Pipeline object doesn't support .deploy method, how to deploy this pipeline?

Pipeline does not have a `.deploy()` method, no

Use `pipeline.upsert(role_arn='...')` to create/update the pipeline definition to SageMaker, then call `pipeline.start()` . Docs [here](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/workflows/pipelines/sagemaker.workflow.pipelines.html#pipeline)

> While inference/scoring, When we receive a raw data(single row for each source), how to trigger the pipeline?

There are actually two types of pipelines in SageMaker. Model Building Pipelines (which you have in your question), and [Serial Inference Pipelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/inference-pipelines.html), which are used for Inference. AWS definitely should have called the former "workflows"

You can use a model building pipeline to setup a serial inference pipeline

To do pre-processing in a serial inference pipeline, you want to train an encoder/estimator (such as SKLearn) and save its model. Then train a learning algorithm, and save its model, then create a [PipelineModel](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/pipeline.html) using both models

Comment: Thanks Neil. How to have the data dependencies when we use PipelineModel? Considering, I have two estimators, `model-1` for pre-processing and `model-2` is learning algorithm. How to pass the data from `model-1` to `model-2` to get predictions?

Comment: @Pythoncoder this happens automatically with a pipeline model. the data set is passed to model-1, sagemaker gets its output, then passes that output to model-2

Comment: Does that mean, the response of model-1 is passed as a request to model-2?

Comment: @Pythoncoder yes. You do want to set an environment variable in Model1 to set the format, such as `"SAGEMAKER_DEFAULT_INVOCATIONS_ACCEPT": "text/csv"`

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan I'm curious: could we use a `ProcessingStep` to run inferences? It has the advantage of being able to run for much longer (24h vs 1h for async inference) and stores the intermediate results in S3. For example, if we use an EventBridge event to start a SageMaker Pipeline to do web-scraping, cleaning of the HTML and then call already managed models (e.g. OpenAI API), it seems possible, as long as we don't require a low latency. WDYT?